# Valgrind: finding conflicting store/load in multithread program

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, valgrind

i am trying to write a program with boost::asio and multiple threads. The program seems to be working fine, but when i run it with the valgrind thread tool drd, I get messages of conflicting store and load operations.

==13740== Thread 2:
==13740== Conflicting store by thread 2 at 0x06265ff0 size 4
==13740==    at 0x40F2B8: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::set_ready_events(unsigned int) (epoll_reactor.hpp:68)
==13740==    by 0x410097: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue&) (epoll_reactor.ipp:430)

etc.

The error messages are rather lengthy due to all the involved boost calls and seem not to include my functions directly. As I said, the program seems to work, but leaving these errors inside the code leaves me with a bad feeling. Is there any good way, to find the problematic locations in the code?

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

A related bug report landed in Ubuntu's bug trackers (**not** the right place IYAM):

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boost1.53/+bug/1243570

  This details a lock order violation detected with Helgrind (not DRD). This is more tangible
- Some **old** but perhaps interesting discussion about this here: http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/06/167818.php

  > My comments on this source code are as follows:
  >
  > - The comments at the bottom of class epoll_reactor say that any 
  >     access of registered_descriptors_ should be protected by 
  >     registered_descriptors_mutex_. However, the method shutdown_service() 
  >     modifies the container registered_descriptors_ but doesn't lock 
  >     registered_descriptors_mutex_.
  > - The method epoll_reactor::register_descriptor() modifies its second 
  >     argument (descriptor_data) such that it points to the newly created 
  >     descriptor_state object. All data members of the struct 
  >     descriptor_state are public, but all accesses must be guarded by a 
  >     lock on descriptor_state::mutex_. So all callers of 
  >     register_descriptor() must be checked in order to verify whether or 
  >     not there are any thread-unsafe accesses of 
  >     descriptor_state::op_queue_ or descriptor_state::shutdown_. Personally 
  >     I never recommended such a class design.
  > - While all accesses of the members of struct descriptor_state should 
  >     be protected by locking descriptor_state::mutex_, no lock is held on 
  >     this last mutex by register_descriptor() when it sets 
  >     descriptor_data::shutdown_ nor by shutdown_service() while it modifies 
  >     descriptor_state::op_queue_ and descriptor_state::shutdown_. The 
  >     former is easy to fix: move the "descriptor_data->shutdown_ = false" 
  >     statement to somewhere before the epoll_ctl() system call.
  >
  > Does one of the above scenarios explain the race report you have observed ?

Of course, many version passed since then (1.43.0-1.55.0) so chances are this has been addressed, or otherwise changed, but it could give you a lead to find more information in the boost trackers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while my error messages are different from the ones quoted in the server example, the cause could indeed be the same. The only thing which worries me is that a get conflicts for writing with different sizes up to 8 byte, so I will have to review my code carefully without the help of tools now.